# Help needed regarding GRUB for Dual Boot from two different SSDs

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, ssd, windows-10, nvme

I am comparatively new to Ubuntu.I have a laptop with Windows10 installed on a 1TB SATA SSD.Today,i added another 240GB NVMe SSD & Installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I can successfully dual boot & change the OS from BIOS.But unlike my Desktop(Where I have Ubuntu & Win7 on two different partitions of a same drive) where the GRUB appears & ask for the Ubuntu & Windows boot manager!
When installing Ubuntu on the NVMe,i totally disconnected the Windows drive to play safe.Somewhere I read that OS-Prober will automatically detect the OS & shows on the GRUB but it's not happening!
What should i do to get the dual boot menu on the GRUB?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you want to be able to boot Windows when the second disk has been removed (without going into UEFI settings/BIOS)? If not, did you try to simply run update-grub (that should get the Windows grub option on the second disk's grub menu)?  If that didn't work, check to see if the /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober has been disabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your promt response.....
What I did was:
1) sudo nano /etc/default/grub
2) Added This line GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
3) sudo os-prober
4) sudo update grub

That added the entry of Windows Boot Manager to the GRUB menu & now i am able to see the dual boot option from GRUB.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Now that you have found a solution, please click on the **Answer Your Own Question** button below and write a detailed answer. After the wait time, click on the gray check mark next to your answer and turn it green. This will mark your problem has been correctly answered, and help others with the same problem.

Comment: You may also want to read [How to write a good answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) for this site in the help section.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Run these commands in sequence

1. sudo nano /etc/default/grub
2. Added This line GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false if not present.Or uncomment,if line present
3. sudo os-prober
4. sudo update grub
5. sudo reboot -h now

That added the entry of Windows Boot Manager to the GRUB menu.Now after reboot,windows boot manager will appear as dual boot option in GRUB